# Set/Get command line system variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables, command-line, system

When I open a windows command prompt and type "set" then enter, I get a list of system variables.

How do I set/get those in C# using visual studio?

I tried:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariableName", "test123");
```

However, when I type "set" into the command line, I don't see my new variable called "TestVariableName" with value of "test123".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you `echo %TestVariableName%`?

Comment: You may not have permission to set environmental variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, the overload of SetEnvironmentVariable that you used "Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable **stored in the current process**." ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable.aspx?ppud=4 ).

You should use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) with an [EvironmentVariableTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx) value of `Machine` if you want it to affect other programs.

Secondly, environment variables are copied from the system or the parent process when a process starts, and never change from the perspective of a running application even if they are changed in the wider system.

In your case, start a new instance of the command line *after* setting the variable and you should see your variable.

Comment: You should also note that child processes inherit the *current* environment of their parent process. Once you modify your own environment, any changes are passed on to any child processes that you subsequently  spawn.

Comment: Thank you!  Got it.  The biggest help here was "start a new instance of command line"

Comment: So, for anyone looking, the answer is:

`System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariableName", "test123", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);`

Comment: Edited to reflect @NicholasCarey's suggestion and the typo in the value of `EnvironmentVariableTarget`.